# multiple TransactionScopes in in different classes C#

Tags: c#, rollback, transactionscope

Good day,
I have a method which contains several database commits (about 15) in a different classes, I need a way to make all the db changes only if the the method did not throw any exception, I am thinking about using a Transaction Scope, and my question is weather i can use a single instance of that Transaction Scope in all the different classes and if not what is the best practice to perform a rollback in case of an exception?
Thanks!

Comment: You should have a singular 'data layer' class which will be responsible for executing the commands. The method(s) in this class should take an argument (perhaps an enum) that indicates how the transactions should be handled (left 'open' or not). Then the methods which call the data layer should catch exceptions and rollback or commit the transactions accordingly.

Comment: You need to investigate UnitOfWork.  What data access technology are you using?  ado.net? Entity Framework? entity framework's DbContext is inherently a unit of work implementation.

Comment: I am using .net framework 4.5

Comment: @Fran UnitOfWork doesn't have anything to do with how transactions are handled. In the end, you *do* need a transaction, ambient or not. DbContext is *not* an implementation of an UoW anyway. It does use explicit transactions internally. In this case, the OP is asking about *two* databases. That means two contexts, hence the need for a TransactionScope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there's nothing in his question that mentions multiple databases, just several commits.  It's not obvious because he hasn't included any code, but UnitOfWork is a transaction.  Technically this could be an local transcation or DTC transaction, but it's still all one unit. but if you just wrap everything in a TranscationScope without changing the underlying classes you could accidentally get your transaction promoted up to a distributed transaction, which could affect performance.

Comment: @Fran UoW is UoW, not a transaction. You may discard the changes but that doesn't mean you aborted the transaction. A *transaction* on the other hand can roll back any changes made by a UoW. EF has explicit support for transaction for this very reason.

Comment: @Fran you may argue that the OP doesn't need, in fact should *not* call SaveChanges all the time and call it just once at the end of the entire request.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with that last statement.  but here's the definition of Unit Of Work - Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems

Comment: @Fran yes. *Business* transaction. That's not DbContext. In fact, that's one of the most annoying antipatterns - using *database transactions* to implement *business transactions*. In one of its worst manifestations, a *database* transaction remains open for the duration of a web request, decimating both database performance and web server throughput

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually don't need to perform rollback explicitly, methods that perform database operations might not even be aware of ambient transaction (that is - you don't need to pass `TransactionScope` to them). Just do:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    FirstDatabaseOperation();
    SecondDatabaseOperation();
    // etc
    tran.Complete();
}
```

If exception happens in any operation - transaction will be rolled back for you, because `TransactionScope` will be disposed.

Comment: every db.commit() is in different class, meaning after every commit is performed my method moves to the next class, will TransactionScope "remember" all the changes made until the tran.Complete();?

Comment: @Coder123 yes, unless you use something unusual to work with database which does not understand `TransactionScope` infrastructure and cannot enlist in current ambient transaciton.

Comment: @Coder123 why perform multiple commits in the first place? Make the changes and call `SaveChanges` once when you are done. `SaveChanges` will send *all* changes to the database, wrapped in a transaction

Comment: @panagiotis Different classes and different tables

Comment: @Coder123 .. don't need different transactions. That's the *point* of using a transaction, to rollback *multiple* changes. You don't need a transaction for a single atomic statement like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. In fact, with ORMs like EF a single call to the DbContext's SaveChanges will use an internal transaction to send all changes to the database - you don't even need a TransactionScope in this case. Multiple SaveChanges and commits are a *very* bad idea.